# Tracking "Back" button events in iOS Google Analytics

Tags: ios, events, google-analytics, analytics

I use [Google's Analytics iOS framework](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/) to track events within my iOS apps.  I am trying to determine if it is good practice to create a tracking event when a user clicks on the Back button of a particular view.  My thought is this will allow me to see "dropoff" points of particular users within my app's flow.

**Is it valuable to create a tracking event for when a user clicks on the "Back" button of a particular view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more common to track when pages (view controllers) open. You know a user tapped back if they go from one page to the next, and it required them to go back. If you have multiple navigational ways to go back, then perhaps it is useful, but I would say that is poor user interface design.

Comment: Yeah, I think you make a good point.  If I just track all page views, I can see in Google Analytics where the drop off points are.  Thanks, coneybeare!